# Passing event from API gateway to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, api-gateway

I have a lambda function that can receive JSON in many different forms. The idea is to receive that through API Gateway. When I test the function using JSON as input, it works fine. However, when I try to test it through API Gateway, it fails because the event is empty.

I tried to add an empty model mapping:

```
{}
```

But I still get the same result. How can I make the API Gateway pass any type of JSON in the body to the function?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I want to use Lambda Proxy integration and I have testing setup with postman and also with API gateway test feature in the AWS console. I'm just doing a POST with the required JSON in the body and the content type headers.

[image]

Comment: How did you test with API-gateway? and  Which integration is API-gateway using? (`Lambda integration` or `Lambda-proxy integration`)

Comment: @SangminKim please see my edit :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need an response model.

When you use a lambda proxy in API gateway you get the data in specific form (https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#example-lambda-proxy-event-default) for full details.

Unlike invoking directly where the `handler(event, ctx, callback)` function allows you to simply do `const payload = event` to get the data you were testing with; you will need to do `const payload = JSON.parse(event.body)`, as the `event` argument contains significantly more information about the full http request.

Comment: I would assume the same applies for python then? Python receives event and context.

Comment: Oh- sorry- don't know why I assumed node. But yes, the event is always the same shape no matter what the language. Annoyingly I've never found a very comprehensive list of events, but this is the closest: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html